# How to insert current date after typing a letter vba

Tags: vba, date

I have a file where I need to take continuously the current date. I write manually the date in column A, and I would like every time I type "d" the current date displays in the format hh:mm. This is the code that i did but (of course) is not working. Online I can´t find any solutions, can you help me? The error is "invalid use of property"

```
Sub Date_Time()

Dim DateCells As Range
'Dim DateCells As Range

'define cells range for inputting dates
Set DateCells = Range(("A16"), Range("A16").End(xlDown))

If DateCells.Activate.Text = "d" Then
    ActiveCell.Insert
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "hh:mm "

End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ctrl+Shift+;` will insert the current time into the selected cell.

- or -

Add this code to the `ThisWorkBook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target = "d" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target = Time
            Target.NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

When you update any cell in the workbook to `d` it will replace that with the current time.

- or -

Record a macro, give it the Shortcut Key of `Ctrl+d` and store it in `Personal Macro Workbook`.

Add this code to the macro:

```
Sub AssignTime()
'
' AssignTime Macro
' Enters the time into the selected cell.
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'

With Selection
    If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
        .Value = Time
        .NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! And do you know what was wrong in my code? You have used a completely different approach

Comment: The first is where it's being called from - you say you want it to fire every time you enter the letter `d`, but I can't see where that's happening.  The second is `.Value = Now` and `.NumberFormat = "hh:mm "` - your code doesn't specify which cell to insert the value into.  `ActiveCell.Value = Now` would place the date/time into the cell. `DateCells= Range(("A16"), Range("A16").End(xlDown))` - this says to start on range A16 and extend down until the next blank cell, which in the case of an empty sheet is the last row so on my test it set a reference to cells A16:A1048576.

Comment: `DateCells.Activate.Text` - trying to Activate all 1048560 cells and check if they contain a single value?  I guess you want check if a single cell contains the letter `d` & not all of them? `ActiveCell.Insert` will just insert a blank cell and has no impact on the `.Value = Time` bit.  `Range(("A16"), Range("A16").End(xlDown))` - you haven't qualified the sheet names, so will always work on the currently active sheet (not a problem if it's running from `WorkSheet_Change` event, but then you'd use `Target`)

Comment: I didn´t get how to then tell the code "if one cell in the xxx range has d then add date". In any case, thank you very much --> Darren 4 life!

Comment: Dear Darren,I just noticed that the code inserts the date, but when I try to delete more cells together (selected with ctrl+alt pressed) I get a bug error 13 "type mismatched". Do you know how to solve it? I tried by adding `code`

Comment: I take it you're using the `Workbook_SheetChange` event.  Add `If Target.Cells.Count=1 Then` as the first line of code, and `End If` as the last.

Comment: Luckily you told me, I just clicked the top arrow but now also the positive mark. let me know if that´s it :)

Comment: Yep, that's the one.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that the code inserts the date, but when I try to delete more cells together (selected with ctrl+alt pressed) I get a bug error 13 "type mismatched". Do you know how to solve it? I tried by adding

```
    Else
```

Application.EnableEvents = False

reload me

But obviously didn´t work